# How Can I Change TextField Toolbar Style?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want change padding/background color/fontSize about TextField's Toolbar.(the toolbar will show when you long press on TextField.).
What should I do?
I read text_field.dart and text_selection.dart but not find answer.

I notice that when I use materialTapTargetSize: `MaterialTapTargetSize.padded` it helpful to change Textfield Toolbar's padding, but I find nothing helpful to change it style such as background color,span color and etc.

here is my code. I simplified the code. This code in main.dart. TextField is in another dart file.

```
MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          minWidth: 0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0), // Notice this
          materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),home:SizedBox()
 )
```

When I change the padding,the TextField Toolbar Padding will changed.I am a bit confused,how can I change it when theme unchanged. I find nothing helpful in TextStyle.

```
TextField(
              style: CustomTextStyle.textField14TextStyle,
              keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
              autocorrect: false,
              enableInteractiveSelection: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: _getHintText(),
                hintStyle: CustomTextStyle.minorGray14TextStyle,
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: widget.isError ? Color(0xffbb424a) : Color(0xff333333)),
                ),
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: widget.isError ? Color(0xffbb424a) : CustomColor.obviousTextColor),
                ),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: Global.isShortScreen ? 15 : 20),
              ),
              onSubmitted: (text) {
                if (widget.onSubmitted != null) {
                  widget.onSubmitted();
                }
              },
              controller: widget.controller,
              cursorColor: CustomColor.obviousTextColor,
            )
```

I try to use something like `Material( child: Theme(data:ThemeData(),child:TextField())` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share SS with us?

Comment: What is SS？@secret35

Comment: Can you share screenshots?

Comment: If you use TextField in Flutter,You will get the same UI,so, screenshots is unuseful.My Question is ask TextField Toolbar,not TextField.If you long press the TextField,the toolbar will show.Can you try it first please?Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For changing text selection color, you can use `textSelectionTheme`

`cursorColor` for the cursor line

`selectionHandleColor` for the bubble below the cursor

`selectionColor` for the highlight color

```
textSelectionTheme: _theme.textSelectionTheme.copyWith(
        cursorColor: AppColors.purple,
        selectionHandleColor: AppColors.purple,
        selectionColor: AppColors.grey4,
 ),
```

For changing text toolbarOption style, you can use `button` `textTheme`

```
textTheme: _theme.textTheme
          .copyWith(
            button: _theme.textTheme.button?.copyWith(
              //here
            ), 
          )
          .apply(fontFamily: GoogleFonts.roboto().fontFamily),
```